# SQL Error ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier - Line 3

Tags: sql, oracle

CODE: ERROR FOR LINE #3 "C" "F_NUM" INVALID IDENTIFIER

```
select g.S_Name, g.C_Name
from GRADE g join CLASS c on g.C_Name = c.C_Name
join FACULTY f on f.F_Num = c.F_Num
where D_Name like '%200AC%';
```

FACULTY (F_Num, F_Name, Rank, D_Name, Salary)

CLASS (C_Name, C_Time, F_Name, C_Room, Semester)

GRADE  (S_Name, C_Name, Grade)

STUDENT (S_Name, ST_Address, GPA)

- The name of students and the name of classes are located in the GRADE table.
- The name of the department is located in the FACULTY table.
- The name of students and the name of classes form the select clause.
- All the three tables are joined in the from clause.
- The name of the department becomes the where clause.

SAMPLE DATA:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf9Iw.png)

Comment: Where is F_Num mentioned?? is it correct?

Comment: @shamnadsherief, yes, the name of students and the name of classes are located in the GRADE table. The name of the department is located in the FACULTY table.
The name of students and the name of classes form the select clause. All the three tables are joined in the from clause. The name of the department becomes the where clause. FACULTY (F_Num, F_Name, Rank, D_Name, Salary), CLASS (C_Name, C_Time, F_Name, C_Room, Semester), and GRADE (S_Name, C_Name, Grade)

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Erm, no. Read my other comment again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLASS (C_Name, C_Time, F_Name, C_Room, Semester) does not have F_Num field defined.

So this statement is causing this error: join FACULTY f on f.F_Num = c.F_Num

Comment: would it be F_NAME ?

Comment: No way to know if F_Num in Faculty is same F_Name in Class table. If F_num is a Number and F_Name is a character field, it may not work. If both fields have  data type, try changing statement to f.F_Num = c.F_Name.

Comment: Can you post sample data from faculty and class table. Probably no matching data between these two tables.

Comment: I'm trying to get the names of students and classes they are taking in room 200AC

Comment: F_Num and F_Name should match up to fetch any data. Check the data in Faculty and Class tables if they match up.

Comment: i uploaded the sample data

Comment: They don't match up in faculty and class tables

Comment: Try changing  f.F_Num = C.F_Name to f.F_Name = C.F_name

Comment: would I have to change it to "where C_ROOM like '%200AC%';"

Answer (score 0):

Error Ora-00904 means you are attempting to execute an SQL statement that is one of the following: The SQL statement includes an invalid column name. The SQL statement includes a column name which does not currently exist.

So first make sure the column F_num is correct.

Comment: the column F_Num does exist

Comment: there maybe some spelling mistake or an unidentified error. You can check through the code where the code doesnt match

Comment: well do @shamnad sherief